# Use pre-defined and dedicated EBS, AMI, S3 with AWS Sagemaker

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-ami

I am trying to use the AWS Sagemaker solution by Amazon and have some questions when launching [notebook instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/gs-setup-working-env.html) (eg. p3.2xlarge)

1. Is it possible to use a pre-defined dedicated EBS volume with the notebook instance? And how?
2. How can we use Ubuntu or any other AMI compared to Amazon Linux for the notebook instance?
3. It is possible to pre-configure the S3 credentials when launching different notebook instances? And possible steps for it.

We can assume that all the EBS/S3 are in the same region as the sagemaker instances.
Re point 2: Amazon Linux AMI in the sagemaker doesn't support awscliv2 or even gcc 5+, making the whole process more cumbersome.
I tried to read through the documentation of AWS Sagemaker but could not find an easy solution. Your help is highly appreciated. Sorry if this is a duplicate.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. If you mean attach an existing EBS volue, the answer is no. You cannot attach an EBS volume to a SM notebook instance because basically the SM notebook instance is launched in service account. You have the option to attach [ML volume storage](http://SageMaker%20attaches%20an%20ML%20storage%20volume%20to%20the%20ML%20compute%20instance) (EBS) which will be deleted in case you terminate the notebook instance.
2. You cannot use a different AMI but you can choose between [Amazon Linux 1 and Amazon Linux 2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/nbi-al2.html). The workaround for this is by using a [custom image with SageMaker Studio.](https://github.com/aws-samples/sagemaker-studio-custom-image-samples)
3. When you launch a NB instance, you choose the IAM role which will be used by the instance. That role will be used to access different resources in your account.